# Integrating $\mathbf{z}$ over a function of shifted vectors $\|\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x}\|$ and $\|\mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y}\|$

Tags: integration, transformation, coordinate-systems, jacobian

Fix two vectors $\mathbf{x} = \left[ \begin{matrix} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{matrix} \right]$ and $\mathbf{y} = \left[ \begin{matrix} y_{1} \\ y_{2} \end{matrix} \right]$. Let's suppose I am interested in the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz_{1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz_{2} \ f\left( \| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \|^{2}, \| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \|^{2} \right)
$$
Where I am integrating over all $\mathbf{z} = \left[ \begin{matrix} z_{1} \\ z_{2} \end{matrix} \right] \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$, and $f$ is a function of the following:
$$
\| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \|^{2} = ( z_{1} - x_{1} )^{2} + ( z_{2} - x_{2} )^{2} \\
\| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \|^{2} = ( z_{1} - y_{1} )^{2} + ( z_{2} - y_{2} )^{2}
$$

Is there a change of coordinates that would make this computation a little simpler? Something a long the lines of polar coordinates would be nice.

I have tried defining the variables $U = \| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} \|^{2}$ and $V = \| \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} \|^{2}$, but I don't think that these variables work well because I don't know how to define the inverse transformation $z_{1} = z_{1}(U,V)$ and $z_{2} = z_{2}(U,V)$ (from which to get the Jacobian matrix).

I have also thought about using elliptical coordinates [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system), but can't seem to understand how to fit this to use in my problem (should I rotate and shift my vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ so that I match the definition used in the wikipedia link, in the sense that $a = \|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}\|$?).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You don’t need to know the inverse map explicitly to compute its Jacobian. The Inverse Function Theorem tells us that the Jacobian of the inverse is the inverse of the Jacobian in some neighborhood of a point at which the Jacobian is nonsingular. That’s almost everywhere for the change of coordinates you’ve proposed.

Comment: Do you know anything about $f$? Depending on its properties, certain coordinates may be preferred.

Comment: My function $f$ is very complicated, this is the function: $f(\mathbf{z}) = \frac{\cosh^{-1}( || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} ||^2 / a + b ) \cosh^{-1}( || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} ||^2 / c + d )}{ \sinh\left( \cosh^{-1}( || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} ||^2 / a + b ) \right) \sinh\left( \cosh^{-1}( || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} ||^2 / c + d ) \right) }$, where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in the two center bipolar coordinate system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-center_bipolar_coordinates).  Here the independent variables are exactly the relevant distances, if you choose x and y as the points through which the line defining this coordinate system pass.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to actually utilize these coordinates? I've been thinking about this....it seems not so straightforward

Comment: You're probably looking for how to find the Jacobian, which is not on the wikipedia site.  I think I actually did this calculation at some point, but unfortunately don't have the results on hand.  It is a worthwhile exercise to try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

So if I define the following two variables:
$$
U := \sqrt{ ( z_{1} - x_{1} )^2 + ( z_{2} - x_{2} )^2 } \\
V := \sqrt{ ( z_{1} - y_{1} )^2 + ( z_{2} - y_{2} )^2 }
$$

Then I think my new variables should run over the limits of integration $U,V \in (0,\infty)$. Also I find that the Jacobian determinant is given by:
$$
\left| \frac{\partial \left( z_{1}, z_{2} \right)}{ \partial \left( U, V \right) } \right| \ = \ \frac{ 2 U V }{ \sqrt{ - \left( (U+V)^2-d^2 \right) \left( (U-V)^2-d^2 \right) } }
$$
...where I have defined the constant $d = ||\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y}|| = \sqrt{( x_{1} - y_{1} )^2 + ( x_{2} - y_{2} )^2}$.

Therefore, my integral of interest now becomes written as:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz_{1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dz_{2} \ f\left( || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{x} ||^2, || \mathbf{z} - \mathbf{y} ||^2 \right) \ = \ \int_{0}^{\infty} dU \int_{0}^{\infty} dV \ f\left( U^2, V^2 \right) \frac{ 2 U V }{ \sqrt{ - \left( (U+V)^2-d^2 \right) \left( (U-V)^2-d^2 \right) } }
$$

My issue now is that the Jacobian is complex-valued for large enough $X$ and $Y$! What can this possibly mean? Is this telling me that these are not valid coordinates?